# "Unexpected symbol" in R

Tags: r

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error

```
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  ans <- logver(theta)-logver(est)
  return exp"
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

This is my code:

```
n <- 27
sum <- 30 + 28 + 26 + 22 + 26 + 27 + 25 + 18 + 34 + 33 + 20 + 25 + 27 + 33 + 31 + 27 + 21 + 30 + 26 + 24 + 30 + 33 + 17 + 28 + 21 + 30 + 27


precision<-0.1                #precision de la rejilla
intervalo<-1                  #parámetro del tamaño del intervalo a graficar

logver <- function (theta) {
  return -27 * theta + log (theta) * sum
}

est<- sum / n;
VR <- function (theta) {              #Verosimilitud Relativa (RV)
  ans <- logver(theta)-logver(est)
  return exp(ans)
}
```

Although, it works fine if I remove the "exp" function call.

Comment: btw, is that 'compiler-errors' tag correct, since R doesn't compile?

Comment: Note that it isn't a good idea to call a variable 'sum' since it is a common function in R.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have no parenthesis for the `return`

```
return(exp(ans))
```

Comment: also in the `logver` function definition